# What's the fastest way of getting a visa for Australia after ETA is refused?

Tags: visas, australia, canadian-citizens, eta, e-visas

I am in Canada and tried applying for the ETA for Australia online. It was deferred and I waited 12 hours to find out that it was not approved.

My flight is in 3 days, is there any way to get an ETA or a visa in time?

I'm a Canadian citizen and my flight is on the 13th of July.

Comment: Can you please add a few more details, like your nationality and the time you expect to be in Australia/

Comment: Have you tried reapplying or asking the airline to apply for you?

Comment: Did it say why you weren't approved ?

Comment: you applied 4 days before your flight? They say to do it two weeks in advance. They might have refused just because of the short notice. I suggest you contact them (eg through http://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa/Immi/immiaccount-technical-support-form ) asap

Comment: No they did not give a reason.

Comment: Why does this question have bounty, it's well past the age where it has any relevance any more.

Comment: @insidesin Mark may be hoping to entice the OP back to give an update/answer.

Comment: And even if it's not relevant to the OP any more and he doesn't return, it could be useful to future readers.

Answer (score 3):

Since ETA is no longer an option, the fastest option is to apply for a [Subclass 600](http://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/600-) Australian visa, also known as a Visitor visa. The [official processing time](http://canada.embassy.gov.au/otwa/StatusCheckA.html) at the Australian consulate in Canada is 4 weeks, with no expedited option available.

Unless you are in a true emergency (such a death of a relative), you will have to postpone your trip.